# Solving coupled exponential equations simultaneously with a given condition

Tags: algorithm, math, simultaneous, exponential, equations

I want to solve the following equations simultaneously to obtain `x_i` 's and T.

```
 x_i =a_i * exp(-C_i / T)    with the condition  sum(x_i)=1
```

where i may be up to 30 in the worst case and 3 at best.  `a_i` and `c_i` are known.

Can any one please suggest an algorithm. I have tried Monte Carlo but could not get the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plug the expressions for `x_i` into the restriction about their sum; you will get an equation for T. You can solve it using [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).